# how to install Phonegap plugin for all platforms

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, documentviewer

I am trying to add a phonegap plugin

```
phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-document-viewer
```

This only installs the plugin for browser.

```
Plugin "cordova-plugin-document-viewer" already installed on browser.
```

I need to install it for all platforms iOS, android and windows phone.
How to do that. can someone suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add your platforms first

```
cordova platform add ios
cordova platform add android
```

Comment: Thank you. But now it is throwing error for android. ANDROID_HOME not set issue. Do I need to install android sdk.

Comment: Hi, yes you do.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that then.

Comment: can you help on how to use the document viewer plugin

Comment: cordova.plugins.SitewaertsDocumentViewer.canViewDocument(
            url, contentType, options, onPossible, onMissingApp, onImpossible, onError);

I am using the below values and it is throwing `"Missing Command Error"` in windows broswer and has "no effect" on iOS.

    cordova.plugins.SitewaertsDocumentViewer.canViewDocument(
        'mylocal.pdf', 'application/pdf', '', onPossible, onMissingApp, onImpossible, onError);